# get substring from string upto any special chars occurs

Tags: java, regex

In java get a substring from string up to any special chars occurs
the below coding is working as expected but in the future, some other special chars exist that need the additional if condition, can we have any regex to get a substring

```
private static String getTruncatedVesselName(String input){
        if(input.contains("/")){
            String output = input.split("/")[0];
            return getSubString(output);
        }
        return getSubString(input);
    }
    private static String getSubString(String output){
        if(output.contains("(")){
            return output.substring(0,output.indexOf("("));
        }
        return output;
    }
```

```
Ex: 
    INPUT                 Expected OUTPUT
   abc def a(xy) / pq           abc def a
   abc def a(xy)                abc def a
   abc def a / pq               abc def a
   abc def a/pq (xy)            abc def a
```

Comment: Trying to get the word at the string start? Then use `^\w+` (`"^\\w+"`).

Comment: Hi Wiktor Stribizew, its not worked tries the below code 
String input = "WADI ALRAYAN / 145W ";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\w+ (\"^\\w+\")");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }

Comment: There is no capturing group, why do you use `.group(1)`? Use `.group(0)` with `"^\\w+"` pattern.

Comment: even using .group(0) still no result

Comment: Wait, you changed the expected output

Answer (score 1):

I assume, if you want a substring until any special character occur in input string, then here is solution below which based on `regex`.

```
String inputs[] = {
    "abc def a(xy) / pq",
    "abc def a(xy)",
    "abc def a / pq",
    "abc def a/pq (xy)"
};

for(String input : inputs) {
    System.out.println(input + "\t" + getSubString(input));
}

private static String getSubString(String input) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\s]*").matcher(input);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        return input.substring(0, matcher.end());
    }
    return input;
}
```

And here is your desired result

```
abc def a(xy) / pq      abc def a
abc def a(xy)           abc def a
abc def a / pq          abc def a 
abc def a/pq (xy)       abc def a
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to match first word or whitespace chars** you can  use

```java
Pattern.compile("^[\\w\\s]+");
```

Or, if you need to support any Unicode words:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?U)^[\\w\\s]+");
```

Here, `^[\w\s]+` matches one or more (`+`) chars that are either letters/digits/underscore (`\w`) or whitespace (`\s`) at the start of the string (`^`).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9fJWKc/2).

**If you want to prevent trailing whitespace**, you can use

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?U)^\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*");
```

See the [Java code](https://ideone.com/9e8pIP):

```java
String s = "abc def a(xy) / pq";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

Output:

```
abc def a
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/9fJWKc/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?:\s+\w+)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `\w+` - one or more word chars

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribizew, not only firs the word, need the substring until the first occurrence of any special char like ( or / in future some other character.

Comment: @HarinathaReddy Yes, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9fJWKc/1). Do not forget the `(?U)` at the start if you need to support any Unicode words.

Comment: Thanks, @Wiltor Stribizew, one corner case is not getting like the spaces before any special char ( 
https://regex101.com/r/blPLpr/1

Comment: @HarinathaReddy If you need the trailing spaces, just add `\s*` at the end, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/blPLpr/2). BTW, in that case, you can even reduce the pattern to `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\w\\s]+");` or `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?U)^[\\w\\s]+");`